# How to sum pairs of 2d arrays in list

Tags: python, numpy

I need a good solution for summing up pairs of 2d vectors.

I want to sum the distance between point1 and point2, point2 and point3... So this has to be done with all pairs (depending on the number of points)

```
a = np.array([[1, 1],[0, 0],[7, 9]])
permutations = [((1, 1), (0, 0), (7, 9)), ((1, 1), (7, 9), (0, 0)), ((0, 0), (1, 1), (7, 9))] ....
```

Now after creating all possible permutations i want to sum the distances in order to specify which order is overall the shortest way.
To get the distance between to points i use:

```
    def calcDistance(a, b):
        d = np.linalg.norm(a-b)
        return d
```

But i don't know how to apply this on a list to get the distance of every pair of points. I tried to do it with for-loops and slicing.

```
for i in range(0, len(permutations), 3):
    print(permutations[i:i+3])
```

As a test it worked, but i have no idea how to apply the calc function on every pair in a list and sum this up again to get a total distance.
The permutations are all stored in one list, so my idea was to go over the n-elements (number of points/vectors) for each iteration.

Comment: What you describe here is a brute force algorithm to find the shortest path between two vertices in a graph. There are other, much more efficient algorithms to do the same thing.

Comment: Exactly, but for practising purposes i want (and have to) solve this problem this way. No matter how inefficient it might be.

Comment: I'm a noob to numpy, so I'd probably write the loops myself even though there's almost certainly a better way to do it with numpy magic. Good luck.

Comment: But i dont know how to write the loops to get this summing-over-blocks-problem solved

Comment: Try to solve a smaller problem: given a path as a tuple of tuples, calculate the length of the path.

Comment: In fact, that needs to be broken into a smaller problem: given two pairs, find the distance between the two points.

Answer (score 1):

Not so elegant for 3 point arrays, but einsum calculations are useful for calculating lengths/distances.  In this case just using your input coordinate sequences and the previously recommended way of creating the point orders

```
import itertools

a = np.array([[1, 1],[0, 0],[7, 9]])

p0 = np.asarray(list(itertools.permutations(a, 3)))

def _cal(a):
    """Perform the calculation, mini-e_leng."""
    diff = a[:-1] - a[1:]
    return np.nansum(np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', diff, diff)))

[_cal(i) for i in p0]
 [12.815967813364475,
 21.40175425099138,
 11.414213562373096,
 21.40175425099138,
 11.414213562373096,
 12.815967813364475]
```

Comment: Ooh nice! Good use of einsum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` to find the one with the maximum difference of each adjacent pair of members.  Also, you can use `itertools` to generate the permutations:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

a = [(1, 1),(0, 0),(7, 9)]
permutations = tuple(itertools.combinations(a,3))
print(permutations)

def calcDistance(a, b):
        d = np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(a)-np.asarray(b))
        return d

most_dist_permutation = max(permutations, key=lambda x:calcDistance(*x[0:2])+calcDistance(*x[1:3]))
print(most_dist_permutation)
```

> ```
> (((1, 1), (0, 0), (7, 9)), ((1, 1), (7, 9), (0, 0)), ((0, 0), (1, 1), (7, 9)), ((0, 0), (7, 9), (1, 1)), ((7, 9), (1, 1), (0, 0)), ((7, 9), (0, 0), (1, 1)))
> ((1, 1), (7, 9), (0, 0))
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used itertools for the permutations like this:

        `permutations = list(itertools.permutations(points))`

I don't think that `max` is the right function for me, i need the shortest way.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
import itertools
ss=list(itertools.permutations(np.arange(0,10), 2))

def calcDistance(a, b):
    d = np.linalg.norm(a-b)
    return d

[calcDistance(np.array(ss).T[0][i],np.array(ss).T[1][i]) for i in range(0,np.array(ss).shape[0])]
```